# Magento Shipping Module: Get all items currently in cart

Tags: magento, module, product

I'm in the middle of developing a shipping module for Magento but get stuck on How to get the items that's currently in the cart for that session.

I follow some tutorial on the internet, they use:

```
if ($request->getAllItems()) { 
    foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
      //do something here.....

    }
}
```

My problem is that **I don't know exactly what info/data that's on the $item variable??**.

I want to get the weight and the price of the product that's currently on the cart to calculate the shipping fee. I tried to print the $item value by using **Mage::log** or printing it to the screen using `print_r` or `var_dump` but it's not successful. The log is empty and the variable won't be printed on screen.

Can somebody inform me of how to get the `$item attributes/method` or is there any other way to get the product information that's currently in cart?

Comment: "My problem is that I don't know exactly what info/data that's on the $item variable??." - You can always "get" all data (attributer) using `$item->getData()` or `$item->debug()`

And for getting methods use `get_class_method(object)`

Answer (score 2):

you can achive this by using one of three methods which are available in `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();`

- `getItemsCollection()` - retrive `sales/quote_items` collection
- `getAllItems()` - retrive all items
- `getAllVisibleItems()` - retrive items which aren't deleted and have `parent_item_id != null`

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this solution and found below. but not tested.

```
$CartSession = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach($CartSession->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)
{
  $productWeight = $item->getWeight();
  $productExPrice  = $item->getPrice(); // price excluding tax
  $productIncPrice = $item->getPriceInclTax(); // price excluding tax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know information about $item, you can do this:

```
print_r($item->getData());
```

If you want to get item weight, here is it:

```
$item->getWeight();
```

Comment: I've tried to print it using print_r, var_dump and also print the item on the log file using Mage::log but nothing printed on the screen and the log is also empty. Note that the shipping calculation is taken at checkout phase which is called using AJAX, hence that maybe the cause that the print to the screen not working

Comment: Try this: print_r($item->getData()); exit; then check your ajax response (I think sometime mage log not working)

Comment: I tried it and the ajax call keep running and never returned (no ajax response)

Comment: AJAX (and not only) may kept running when object you're trying to output is to big.

Using `Mage::log($object->debug(), null, 'my.log.name.log');` should work.

If not i suggest you look for errors in apache and magento logs.

Comment: thanks for $object->debug() , it can print the object on the log and I'm able to get the object info